# Kendo UI Chart - Handling Daylight savings

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have a chart that is displaying half hour data **which breaks when the day in question contains daylight savings.**

I am parsing the date as a javascript date and the chart breaks when you have two different time zones in the category field.

I have tried using UTC as well as showing the date in "2015-11-01T00:30:00Z" string.

Either the graph totally breaks (and causes chrome to 'snap') or it displays a single point with messed up data in the case of the UTC string.

I have tried using the `kendo.parseDate` but no avail.

My `baseUnit` is hours - of course if I change it to days, then suddenly it's ok again and happily draws the chart.

The date is coming from a WCF service so looks like

```
/Date(1446940800000+0000)/
```

I strip out the first part 1446940800000 and then convert this to a javascript date, before adding it to a data source for passing to the chart

```
    var numDate = dpArray[i]._D.substr(dpArray[i]._D.indexOf("(") + 1, 13);
    var d = new Date(numDate);
```

Comment: You need to include more code, can you post the code you're using?

Comment: added the code to convert the wcf date to a javascript object